# Reference Textbooks at one place

Tags: discussion

> > [Can anybody recommend me a topology textbook?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150556/can-anybody-recommend-me-a-topology-textbook)
> >
> > [Introductory book on Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94242/introductory-book-on-topology)
> >
> > [Best book for topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology)
> >
> > [Choosing a text for a First Course in Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903/choosing-a-topology-text)

All these are multiple posts on choosing a reference text for Topology. I am wondering, is it possible to make post where reference texts for various topics are written with a little bit of explanation why that book is good for using as a reference?? I think, this will be handy for many users who request for reference texts.

Comment: An alternative is to use the [list of all questions tagged with both (general-topology) and (reference-request)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request+general-topology).

Comment: Yeah it may be. I am asking like present a complete set of reference texts for various topics like algebra, topology, analysis etc., all at one place.

Comment: This is the sort of post type that would fit nicely on a [blog](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/does-our-site-need-a-blog-like-a-few-sites-on-the-network-have), if we were to have one. It would be very easy to consolidate references, their levels, and why people recommended them.

Comment: Yesterday I was discussing with @ErikNaslund whether these four posts should be merged. He said he would discuss it with the other moderators by email. I added these four posts to the [List of generalizations of Common Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) for reference.

Comment: Such a post seems like a necesaty, it will reduce the number of different post asking this, save time for anyone that searches such posts and will be a great value in general!

Comment: @Mark: I think it may be nice to actually create a separate section in that question, or perhaps even a separate question (maybe we can commandeer this one?) for book recommendation questions. The problem with merging is that sometimes book recommendation questions are specific to a background given by the OP, and in those cases mergers don't necessarily make sense.